# Space Invader Style Game - Model / Presenter Decoupled From View - Functional Again Too

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, game, vba, excel

Thank you for your patience. The game is fully functional again!

I have tried to incorporate all the advice I have received so far. Thank you for taking the time to review and comment.

I have now decoupled the Model / Presenter from the View as much as VBA allows (please correct me if wrong). There are two functions from inside the view which the presenter calls. One of these functions ends the game, the other takes in a collection which the view promptly displays to the player.

When your ship collides with a space object you get a game over message box and then the userform unloads, an upgrade over the previous version which lead to crashes when you tried to run game twice.

Rather than throwing all of the spaceobjects into a single collection I have kept the separate collections for each "type" of spaceobject; incoming, missile and ship. Separate Collections for these objects makes handling collisions and object removal more manageable.

In the immediate term I want to re introduce scoring and a missile count limit. Also I need to fix the scaling of the objects. I have them in a ratio with gameboard height / width. Somehow it was not working for me? Then I am thinking about heat seeking missiles (give me a chance to work on algorithim stuff a bit, should be fun)

You can find the workbook here:

https://github.com/Evanml2030/Excel-SpaceInvader

Note that you cannot import and run Gameboard.frm without the corresponding Gameboard.frx file. Frx is a proprietary Microsoft file type that degenerates into alien symbols inside notepad, not sure how to link here.

Also note that StopWatch, BoardDimensions and each of the Collections have

```
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
```

Big ups to:

StopWatch was put together by the fellow who runs bytecomb, a great site for vba tips. Link: https://bytecomb.com/accurate-performance-timers-in-vba/

**GameBoard.frm:**

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin {C62A69F0-16DC-11CE-9E98-00AA00574A4F} GameBoard 
   Caption         =   "UserForm1"
   ClientHeight    =   9495
   ClientLeft      =   120
   ClientTop       =   465
   ClientWidth     =   10095
   OleObjectBlob   =   "GameBoard.frx":0000
   StartUpPosition =   1  'CenterOwner
End
Attribute VB_Name = "GameBoard"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    GameLogic.RunGame Me.InsideHeight, Me.InsideWidth
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim passVal                                                         As Long
    Select Case KeyCode.Value
    Case 37, 39, 32
        passVal = CInt(KeyCode)
        GameLogic.HandleSendKeys passVal
    End Select
End Sub

Public Sub RefreshGameBoard(ByVal ControlsToAdd As Collection)
    Dim Ctrl                                                            As Image
    Dim SpaceObjectIndex                                                As Variant

    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        Me.Controls.Remove Ctrl.Name
    Next Ctrl

    For SpaceObjectIndex = 1 To ControlsToAdd.Count
        Set Ctrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Name, True)
        Ctrl.Left = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Left
        Ctrl.Top = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top
        Ctrl.Height = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Height
        Ctrl.Width = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Width
        Ctrl.Picture = LoadPicture(LinkToImage(ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).SpaceObjectType))
        Ctrl.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
    Next SpaceObjectIndex
End Sub

Public Sub CloseGame()
    MsgBox "GAMEOVER"
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Function LinkToImage(ByVal SpaceObjectType As SpaceObjectType) As String
    Select Case SpaceObjectType
    Case Alien
        LinkToImage = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\AlienShip.jpg"
    Case Comet
        LinkToImage = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\Comet.jpg"
    Case Star
        LinkToImage = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\Star.jpg"
    Case Missile
        LinkToImage = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\Missile.jpg"
    Case Ship
        LinkToImage = "C:\Users\evanm\OneDrive\Desktop\Excel\SpaceInvader\SpaceShip.jpg"
    End Select
End Function
```

**GameLogic.bas:**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "GameLogic"
Option Explicit

Public Enum SpaceObjectType
    Alien = 1
    Comet = 2
    Star = 3
    Missile = 4
    Ship = 5
End Enum

Public Enum PlayerShipHit
    Hit = 1
    NotHit = 0
End Enum

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
Const Interval = 3

Sub RunGame(ByVal BoardWith As Long, ByVal BoardHeight As Long)
    Dim SleepWatch                                                          As StopWatch
    Dim GenerateIncSpaceObjectsRound1                                       As StopWatch

    BoardDimensions.Width = BoardWith
    BoardDimensions.Height = BoardHeight

    Set SleepWatch = New StopWatch
    SleepWatch.Start

    Set GenerateIncSpaceObjectsRound1 = New StopWatch
    GenerateIncSpaceObjectsRound1.Start

    InitializePlayerShip

    Do
        GameBoard.RefreshGameBoard CombineCollections

        MoveSpaceObjects.MoveIncomingMissiles
        MoveSpaceObjects.MoveIncomingSpaceObjects

        Collisions.HandleMissileCollisions
        If Collisions.HandleShipCollisions Then Exit Do

        If Format(GenerateIncSpaceObjectsRound1.Elapsed, "0.000000") > 3.25 Then
            ReleaseIncomingSpaceObject
            ReleaseIncomingSpaceObject
            ReleaseIncomingSpaceObject
            GenerateIncSpaceObjectsRound1.Restart
        End If

        If Format(SleepWatch.Elapsed, "0.000000") < Interval Then
            Sleep Interval - Format(SleepWatch.Elapsed, "0.000000")
            SleepWatch.Restart
        End If

        DoEvents
    Loop

    GameBoard.CloseGame
End Sub

Public Sub HandleSendKeys(ByVal KeyCode As Long)
    Select Case KeyCode
    Case 37
        MoveSpaceObjects.MoveShip Left
    Case 39
        MoveSpaceObjects.MoveShip Right
    Case 32
        LaunchMissile
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function InitializePlayerShip()
    Dim PlayerShip                                                          As ISpaceObject
    Set PlayerShip = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObject(Ship)
    CollectionShips.Add PlayerShip
End Function

Private Function LaunchMissile()
    Dim LaunchedMissile                                                     As ISpaceObject
    Set LaunchedMissile = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObject(Missile)
    CollectionMissiles.Add LaunchedMissile
End Function

Private Function ReleaseIncomingSpaceObject()
    Dim IncomingSpaceObject                                                 As ISpaceObject
    Set IncomingSpaceObject = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObject(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 3))
    CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Add IncomingSpaceObject
End Function

Private Function CombineCollections() As Collection
    Dim ISpaceObjectIndex                                                   As Long

    Set CombineCollections = New Collection

    For ISpaceObjectIndex = 1 To CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count
        CombineCollections.Add CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(ISpaceObjectIndex)
    Next ISpaceObjectIndex

    For ISpaceObjectIndex = 1 To CollectionMissiles.Count
        CombineCollections.Add CollectionMissiles.Item(ISpaceObjectIndex)
    Next ISpaceObjectIndex

    For ISpaceObjectIndex = 1 To CollectionShips.Count
        CombineCollections.Add CollectionShips.Item(ISpaceObjectIndex)
    Next ISpaceObjectIndex
End Function
```

**MoveSpaceObjects.bas:**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "MoveSpaceObjects"
Option Explicit

Public Enum Direction
    Left = 0
    Right = 1
End Enum

Sub MoveIncomingMissiles()
    Dim SpaceObjectIndex                                                    As Variant

    For SpaceObjectIndex = CollectionMissiles.Count To 1 Step -1
        If CollectionMissiles.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top - 3 <= 0 Then
            CollectionMissiles.Remove SpaceObjectIndex
        Else
            CollectionMissiles.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top = CollectionMissiles.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top - 3
        End If
    Next SpaceObjectIndex
End Sub

Sub MoveIncomingSpaceObjects()
    Dim SpaceObjectIndex                                                    As Variant

    For SpaceObjectIndex = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
        If CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top + 3 >= BoardDimensions.Height Then
            CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Remove SpaceObjectIndex
        Else
            CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top + 3
        End If
    Next SpaceObjectIndex
End Sub

Sub MoveShip(ByVal MoveShipDirection As Direction)
    Select Case MoveShipDirection
    Case Direction.Left
        If CollectionShips.Item(1).Left - 4 >= 0 Then
            CollectionShips.Item(1).Left = CollectionShips.Item(1).Left - 5
        Else
            CollectionShips.Item(1).Left = 0
        End If
    Case Direction.Right
        If (CollectionShips.Item(1).Left + CollectionShips.Item(1).Width) < BoardDimensions.Width Then
            CollectionShips.Item(1).Left = CollectionShips.Item(1).Left + 4
        Else
            CollectionShips.Item(1).Left = BoardDimensions.Width - CollectionShips.Item(1).Width
        End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

**SpaceObjectFactory.bas**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "SpaceObjectFactory"
Option Explicit

Public Function NewSpaceObject(ByVal SpaceObjectType As SpaceObjectType) As Spaceobject
    Select Case SpaceObjectType
    Case Alien
        Set NewSpaceObject = NewSpaceObjectAlien
    Case Comet
        Set NewSpaceObject = NewSpaceObjectComet
    Case Missile
        Set NewSpaceObject = NewSpaceObjectMissile
    Case Ship
        Set NewSpaceObject = NewSpaceObjectShip
    Case Star
        Set NewSpaceObject = NewSpaceObjectStar
    End Select
End Function

Private Function NewSpaceObjectAlien() As Spaceobject
    With New Spaceobject
        .SetInitialLeft Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, BoardDimensions.Width)
        .SetInitialTop 1
        .Height = BoardDimensions.Width / 10
        .Width = BoardDimensions.Width / 10
        .SpaceObjectType = Alien
        .Name = "INCSPACEOBJECT" & CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count
        Set NewSpaceObjectAlien = .Self
    End With
End Function

Private Function NewSpaceObjectComet() As Spaceobject
    With New Spaceobject
        .SetInitialLeft Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, BoardDimensions.Width)
        .SetInitialTop 1
        .Height = BoardDimensions.Height / 7
        .Width = BoardDimensions.Height / 7
        .SpaceObjectType = Comet
        .Name = "INCSPACEOBJECT" & CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count
        Set NewSpaceObjectComet = .Self
    End With
End Function

Private Function NewSpaceObjectMissile() As Spaceobject
    With New Spaceobject
        .SetInitialLeft ((CollectionShips.Item(1).Width - (BoardDimensions.Width / 20)) / 2) + CollectionShips.Item(1).Left
        .SetInitialTop CollectionShips.Item(1).Top - BoardDimensions.Height / 15
        .Height = BoardDimensions.Height / 15
        .Width = BoardDimensions.Height / 20
        .SpaceObjectType = Missile
        .Name = "MISSILE" & CollectionMissiles.Count
        Set NewSpaceObjectMissile = .Self
    End With
End Function

Private Function NewSpaceObjectShip() As Spaceobject
    With New Spaceobject
        .SetInitialLeft BoardDimensions.Width / 2 - ((BoardDimensions.Height / 7) / 2)
        .SetInitialTop Round(BoardDimensions.Height - ((BoardDimensions.Height / 7) * 1.25), 0)
        .Height = BoardDimensions.Height / 7
        .Width = BoardDimensions.Width / 7
        .SpaceObjectType = Ship
        .Name = "SHIP"
        Set NewSpaceObjectShip = .Self
    End With
End Function

Private Function NewSpaceObjectStar() As Spaceobject
    With New Spaceobject
        .SetInitialLeft Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, BoardDimensions.Width)
        .SetInitialTop 1
        .Height = BoardDimensions.Height / 5
        .Width = BoardDimensions.Height / 5
        .SpaceObjectType = Star
        .Name = "INCSPACEOBJECT" & CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count
        Set NewSpaceObjectStar = .Self
    End With
End Function
```

**Collisions.bas:**

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Collisions"
Option Explicit

Sub HandleMissileCollisions()
    Dim MissileObject                                                       As ISpaceObject
    Dim IncomingSpaceObject                                                 As ISpaceObject
    Dim MissileObjectsIndex                                                 As Long
    Dim IncomingSpaceObjectIndex                                            As Long

    For MissileObjectsIndex = CollectionMissiles.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set MissileObject = CollectionMissiles.Item(MissileObjectsIndex)
        For IncomingSpaceObjectIndex = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set IncomingSpaceObject = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(IncomingSpaceObjectIndex)
            If CheckIfCollided(MissileObject, IncomingSpaceObject) Then
                CollectionMissiles.Remove MissileObjectsIndex
                CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Remove IncomingSpaceObjectIndex
                Exit For
            End If
        Next IncomingSpaceObjectIndex
    Next MissileObjectsIndex
End Sub

Function HandleShipCollisions() As Boolean
    Dim ShipObject                                                          As ISpaceObject
    Dim IncomingSpaceObject                                                 As ISpaceObject
    Dim ShipObjectIndex                                                     As Long
    Dim IncomingSpaceObjectIndex                                            As Long

    For ShipObjectIndex = CollectionShips.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set ShipObject = CollectionShips.Item(ShipObjectIndex)
        For IncomingSpaceObjectIndex = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set IncomingSpaceObject = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(IncomingSpaceObjectIndex)
            If CheckIfCollided(ShipObject, IncomingSpaceObject) Then
                HandleShipCollisions = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next IncomingSpaceObjectIndex
    Next ShipObjectIndex
End Function

Private Function CheckIfCollided(ByVal First As ISpaceObject, ByVal Second As ISpaceObject) As Boolean
    Dim HorizontalOverlap                                                   As Boolean
    Dim VerticalOverlap                                                     As Boolean

    HorizontalOverlap = (First.Left - Second.Width < Second.Left) And (Second.Left < First.Left + First.Width)
    VerticalOverlap = (First.Top - Second.Height < Second.Top) And (Second.Top < First.Top + First.Height)
    CheckIfCollided = HorizontalOverlap And VerticalOverlap
End Function
```

**CollectionMissiles.cls:**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CollectionMissiles"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private CollectionMissiles As Collection
Private pCount As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set CollectionMissiles = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set CollectionMissiles = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(obj As ISpaceObject)
    CollectionMissiles.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(index As Variant)
    CollectionMissiles.Remove index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(index As Variant) As ISpaceObject
    Set Item = CollectionMissiles.Item(index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = CollectionMissiles.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set CollectionMissiles = New Collection
End Sub
```

**CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.cls:**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(obj As ISpaceObject)
    CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(index As Variant)
    CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Remove index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(index As Variant) As ISpaceObject
    Set Item = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Item(index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set CollectionIncomingSpaceObjects = New Collection
End Sub
```

**CollectionShips.cls:**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CollectionShips"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private CollectionShips As Collection
Private pCount As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set CollectionShips = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set CollectionShips = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(obj As ISpaceObject)
    CollectionShips.Add obj
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(index As Variant)
    CollectionShips.Remove index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(index As Variant) As ISpaceObject
    Set Item = CollectionShips.Item(index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = CollectionShips.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set CollectionShips = New Collection
End Sub
```

**ISpaceObject.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ISpaceObject"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Public Property Let Left(ByVal changeLeft As Long)
End Property

Public Property Get Left() As Long
End Property

Public Property Let Top(ByVal changeTop As Long)
End Property

Public Property Get Top() As Long
End Property

Public Property Get Width() As Long
End Property

Public Property Get Height() As Long
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property

Public Property Get SpaceObjectType() As SpaceObjectType
End Property

Private Function IsMissile() As Boolean
End Function

Private Function IsIncomingSpaceObject() As Boolean
End Function
```

**BoardDimensions.cls:**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "BoardDimensions"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private Type BoardDimensionsData
    Width As Long
    Height As Long
End Type

Private this As BoardDimensionsData

Public Property Let Width(ByVal Width As Long)
    this.Width = Width
End Property

Public Property Get Width() As Long
    Width = this.Width
End Property

Public Property Let Height(ByVal Height As Long)
    this.Height = Height
End Property

Public Property Get Height() As Long
    Height = this.Height
End Property
```

**StopWatch.cls**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "StopWatch"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" ( _
lpPerformanceCount As UINT64) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" ( _
lpFrequency As UINT64) As Long

Private pFrequency                                                          As Double
Private pStartTS                                                            As UINT64
Private pEndTS                                                              As UINT64
Private pElapsed                                                            As Double
Private pRunning                                                            As Boolean

Private Type UINT64
    LowPart                                                                 As Long
    HighPart                                                                As Long
End Type

Private Const BSHIFT_32 = 4294967296#            ' 2 ^ 32

Private Function U64Dbl(U64 As UINT64) As Double
    Dim lDbl                                                                As Double
    Dim hDbl                                                                As Double
    lDbl = U64.LowPart
    hDbl = U64.HighPart
    If lDbl < 0 Then lDbl = lDbl + BSHIFT_32
    If hDbl < 0 Then hDbl = hDbl + BSHIFT_32
    U64Dbl = lDbl + BSHIFT_32 * hDbl
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim PerfFrequency As UINT64
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    pFrequency = U64Dbl(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Property Get Elapsed() As Double
    If pRunning Then
        Dim pNow As UINT64
        QueryPerformanceCounter pNow
        Elapsed = pElapsed + (U64Dbl(pNow) - U64Dbl(pStartTS)) / pFrequency
    Else
        Elapsed = pElapsed
    End If
End Property

Public Sub Start()
    If Not pRunning Then
        QueryPerformanceCounter pStartTS
        pRunning = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Pause()
    If pRunning Then
        QueryPerformanceCounter pEndTS
        pRunning = False
        pElapsed = pElapsed + (U64Dbl(pEndTS) - U64Dbl(pStartTS)) / pFrequency
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Reset()
    pElapsed = 0
    pRunning = False
End Sub

Public Sub Restart()
    pElapsed = 0
    QueryPerformanceCounter pStartTS
    pRunning = True
End Sub

Public Property Get Running() As Boolean
    Running = pRunning
End Property
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is confusing. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Looks like you've read some of my work. I invite you to re-read these posts, for I strongly advise *against* using the `PredeclaredId` like you did here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> Private Function InitializePlayerShip()
>     Dim PlayerShip                                                          As ISpaceObject
>     Set PlayerShip = SpaceObjectFactory.NewSpaceObject(Ship)
>     CollectionShips.Add PlayerShip
> End Function
> ```

I really, really, *really* don't like this indentation style that shoves data types as far to the right as possible. The fact that, while consistent within modules, it's inconsistent across the project, makes it very distracting, and harder to parse what variable is of what data type - especially when there's a wall of declarations:

> ```
> Private pFrequency                                                          As Double
> Private pStartTS                                                            As UINT64
> Private pEndTS                                                              As UINT64
> Private pElapsed                                                            As Double
> Private pRunning                                                            As Boolean
> ```

Use an [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to apply consistent indenting style across the entire project: don't change the rules depending on which module you're looking at. If fixed-column data types rocks your boat, configure the indenter as such, and use that. But don't switch indentation styles between modules.

That `Function InitializePlayerShip` procedure has no declared return type, and doesn't assign any; it returns an implicit `Variant/Empty` for no reason, every time it's invoked. Make it a `Sub` if you don't care for a return value.

`CollectionShips.Add PlayerShip` is very worrying: you're storing application state in your classes' *default instance*, which effectively turns that state into global state. This is *exactly* what's wrong with storing state in default instances, and why it should be avoided at all costs: you might as well replace all these `PredeclaredId` classes with standard modules. They're full-fledged objects, but you're treating them like global state that can be accessed from anywhere: passing an instance as a parameter becomes useless/redundant, since the instance is already global.

`VB_PredeclaredId` isn't wrong in itself. In fact, I use it all the time. But **NEVER** use it to turn a class into some global-scope data bag. Every single time I enable the predeclared ID on a class, I use it to expose a convenient *factory method*, and ensure I never, ever use that default instance as I would any other instance of the same type. **Storing state in the default instance defeats the very purpose of having class modules in the first place.**

Every single `Collection*` class is redundant and should be removed. If you need a collection of ships, use a `Collection` and put ships in it.

Everything in `SpaceObjectFactory.bas` belongs in `SpaceObject`; only the `SpaceObject` class should ever need to use the `SpaceObject` type - everything else only needs to see `ISpaceObject`. That factory method belongs on the default instance, and the `SpaceObjectType` enum belongs in the `ISpaceObject` interface module. *Having a factory method on the class you're creating IS the reason for a `.Self` property and having a default instance* - without a factory method, there's pretty much no reason to have a `PredeclaredId`.

The `IsMissile` and `IsIncomingSpaceObject` properties smell: you're special-casing one `SpaceObjectType` and treating it differently from the others - from an OOP point of view, that's pretty much a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle. What's special about a `Missile`? What's special about an "incoming space object"? You don't need either - you need a `Direction` and `Speed` values, perhaps encapsulated in some `Vector` class, exposed as a property on `ISpaceObject` - and now if you want you can have space objects coming from any direction, at varying speeds! Not that it's in the specs, but the point is, an `ISpaceObject` shouldn't care whether it's an `Alien` or a `Missile`, with the unwritten assumption that the `Missile` moves upward - using a `Vector` or a combination of `Direction` and `Speed` removes that assumption and makes every implementation equal.

Comment: Matt, "IsMIssile, and "IsIncomingSpaceObject" were based on a previous comment of mine (see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204564/space-invader-game-written-in-vba-3rd-iteration), but not implemented the way it should. These are static helper properties and should **not** be re-written for each inheritance. Missile and non-missile have special meaning in the game - but my linked answer identified issues with logic, did not fix them.

Comment: @AJD I know - but given a `Direction` (or some vector), it doesn't matter anymore, does it?

Comment: ... and that they are not used in the code? :-)

Comment: Don't have time to write an answer myself today - another key point about the custom collection classes is that they do not do any custom stuff!

Comment: @AJD I might have misread the OP then... my impression was that `IsMissile` was used for determining whether to move the object up or down - so my idea is to generalize the object as much as possible: things move in some direction (at some rate), so store that information with the object and then it doesn't matter if it's a "missile" or an "incoming space object". Ideally every single drawable object would have the exact same interface: where to draw the object, where it's going, at what pace, what size is it, and what image to use for it.

Comment: Funny enough I forgot to remove the isincomingspaceobject and ismissile after resperating objects into separate collections. I do not call these properties in code. @AJD your post was not entirely in vain! :I was playing with indenter a bit, thank you for link finally think i have it figured out. :-p I agree re getting rid of the global collections. Will create collections and pass. Will move factory into spaceobject class itself. Will try to create direction / speed. As for storing image in class, was thinking leave to view? View may be worksheet cells...

Comment: as for why i used custom collections. i think for some reason it made it "neater" to me, but I will rework this again this weekend. thank you for input will read over a few times and rework. eventually this may be a nifty VBA game.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: `IsMIssile` etc was to originally determine actions after collision, but OP has found a different way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

### File Paths

It is best to use relative references when lining to external files.

> ```
> Private Function LinkToImage(ByVal SpaceObjectType As SpaceObjectType) As String
>     Dim Path As String
>     Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
>     Select Case SpaceObjectType
>     Case Alien
>         LinkToImage = Path & "AlienShip.jpg"
>     Case Comet
>         LinkToImage = Path & "Comet.jpg"
>     Case Star
>         LinkToImage = Path & "Star.jpg"
>     Case Missile
>         LinkToImage = Path & "Missile.jpg"
>     Case Ship
>         LinkToImage = Path & "SpaceShip.jpg"
>     End Select
> End Function
> ```

### Images

Consider converting the JPEG files to GIFs and deleting their backgrounds and setting the image `BorderStyle` and `BackStyle` properties to transparent.

I would also add an Userform to store the default images.  You could also have this form double as your SpaceObject factory.  In this way, you will not have to distribute multiple file.

### SpaceObject

Consider storing an internal reference to SpaceObject image and returning it as a default value.

> ```
> Property Get Value() As Long
>     Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
>     Set Value = this.Image
> End Property
> ```

SpaceObjects should only be destroyed when they leave the board.  This will reduce the flickering.  You will have to add `Move` and `Intersect` methods to the `SpaceObject` class.

The program seems to lag as more images are added to the Userform. Adding the max number images that will be needed to the userform in design mode instead of adding them at run time should result in an even frame rate.  I would think it would also improve the overall performance.

### Demo

Just for a quick demo, I converted the images to GIFs, deleted their backgrounds and loaded them into a Userform. Ideally, I would store the images in an ImageList but I don't think that Imagelists are currently supported.  It seems that this technique is actually quite faster then loading the images from file.  To adjust for the faster loading I had to change the game's interval rate from 3 to 20 for my demo.

[image]

Next I added a quick hack to make it work

> ```
> Public Sub RefreshGameBoard(ByVal ControlsToAdd As Collection)
>     Dim Ctrl                                                            As Image
>     Dim SpaceObjectIndex                                                As Variant
>
>     For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
>         Me.Controls.Remove Ctrl.Name
>     Next Ctrl
>
>     For SpaceObjectIndex = 1 To ControlsToAdd.Count
>         Set Ctrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Name, True)
>         Ctrl.Left = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Left
>         Ctrl.Top = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Top
>         Ctrl.Height = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Height
>         Ctrl.Width = ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).Width
>         'Ctrl.Picture = LoadPicture(LinkToImage(ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).SpaceObjectType))
>         CopyPicture Ctrl, ControlsToAdd.Item(SpaceObjectIndex).SpaceObjectType
>         Ctrl.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
>     Next SpaceObjectIndex
> End Sub
>
> Sub CopyPicture(Ctrl As MSForms.Image, SpaceObjectType As SpaceObjectType)
>     Select Case SpaceObjectType
>     Case Alien
>         Ctrl.Picture = DefaultImagesForm.AlienShip.Picture
>     Case Comet
>         Ctrl.Picture = DefaultImagesForm.Comet.Picture
>     Case Star
>         Ctrl.Picture = DefaultImagesForm.Star.Picture
>     Case Missile
>         Ctrl.Picture = DefaultImagesForm.Missile.Picture
>     Case Ship
>         Ctrl.Picture = DefaultImagesForm.SpaceShip.Picture
>     End Select
>     Ctrl.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
>     Ctrl.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
> End Sub
> ```

[image]

Note:  The actual game does not flicker as much as the GIF.

---

### Addendum: Collision Detection

[image]

Added Intersects Method to `SpaceObject`
`DefaultImagesForm` new generates code for `SpaceObjectFactory`

[Download Sample Workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tv5InIFq29GBO-5-sjNZj8PtLN_bdZ4l)

Comment: really like this. but the lack of a boundary makes it sort of lame, a collision does not look like it occurs. however there may be a way of checking whether a collision of game pieces occurs, by figuring out how much space an object takes within the control. the primary part of your post, storing images within a userform inside application rather than as a file, is gold. thank you!

Comment: also the gif rather than jpg is solid too...for some reason it never occurred to me to look at what these file types do to the data...until your post.

Comment: may have to come up with a nifty way to check too, as adding frames to the objects will greatly increase the number of checks per object on the board. for incoming we only need model the bottom, and vice versa for outgoing. still we will now be checking each frame..and have to keep track of which frames belong to which object. i agree that this is the way forward though, makes game feel much more legit.

Comment: may also edit the missile to even out wings....cheat a little LOL

Comment: trying to figure a way to get bitmap out of image.picture, then return that bitmap or even a pointer to image.picture, then set my spaceobject.picture to that bitmap. cant used loadpicture, that only takes string to a filepath. going to work on this! may have to use some winapi calls

Comment: @learnAsWeGo [Download Sample Workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tv5InIFq29GBO-5-sjNZj8PtLN_bdZ4l).  I implemented the Bounding Box collision detection.  Keep in mind that I did the bare to get it working.   Hopefully, it will help you complete your vision for the game.

Comment: was able to turn the copypicture sub into a function. can return picture to generic "object" which i think is really a pointer to the picture inside of image control. am going to work on frames this weekend. put in most of suggestions from above too. now 5 classes, 3 mods and 2 user forms. working ok!

Comment: I think that it's technically a [HDC (Handle to Device Context)](http://winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html) which I guess is specific type of pointer.

Comment: I've been anticipating the next phase in your project.  Glad to hear that it's coming soon!

Comment: see github for latest updates - https://github.com/Evanml2030/SpaceInvader. flickering persists as i have not had time to change the loop in view that shows the image controls! aside from that this game needs a boss, and as Mathieu suggested i added move north south east west directions, but i suspect there is a better way. I did add hitboxes. someday will finish this up! thank you for help.

Comment: @learnAsWeGo The game looks sharp.  I absolutely love the new Sun image.  It plays pretty good too.  I suspect that it will alway flicker some but I am sure that it will get better, as you continue to work on it.   It looks like you haven't finished implementing North and South movements.  You might consider limiting North to 50% of the Board + half Ship Height.   The game has come a long way.  Two thumbs up from me!